# mongodb compass is not using "text" index for searching a regex expression

Tags: mongodb

I want to search in mongodb a regex expression using text index (I believe for regex search this one is most beneficial).

There is only one field on which to carry out the query. I have created the index like

```
{ "final : "text"}
```

using mongodb compass.

and then when i use this command in integrated mongosh terminal,

```
 db.hello1.find({"final" : { $regex: 'Cleanser', $options: 'i' }}).hint({final : "text"}).explain()
```

It gives me the following error:

```
planner returned error :: caused by :: hint provided does not correspond to an existing index
```

While clearly the compound index exits, of type text _fts(text) _ftsx.

Can someone guide me around this ?

Comment: [Text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#text-indexes) only support [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#-text) queries.

Comment: done !! sorry a bit late :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not designed that way

> Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and is unable to utilize case-insensitive indexes.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)

Comment: hmm, thanks, is there any workaround this to speed these type of queries ?

Comment: As Joe mentioned you need to use only text search or case sensitive searches